# A property of the tensor product of modules in Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, tensor-products

The following theorem is from the Abstract Algebra by Dummit and Foote (in the section 10.4 tensor products of modules):
[image]

Would anybody illustrate how Theorem 8 is used to get
$$
\textrm{ker }\iota\subset\textrm{ker }\varphi
$$
in the proof?

---

[image]

Comment: Let me just say that although I greatly admire D&F, learning tensors from here as your first reference can be incredibly difficult, because they don't assume their rings are commutative, thus leading to this business about left/right/bi-modules. Even if you intend to work in non-commutative algebra one day, you may find it easier to study tensors over commutative rings first, and then come back to D&F.

Comment: @Future Aluffi's book $\textit{Algebra: Chapter 0}$ does exactly what you mention. Actually, almost everything in that book is done over commutative rings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second sentence of the proof of Corollary 9 is kind of poorly phrased.  Here's a clearer phrasing:

> Suppose now that $L$ is an $S$-module, $K\subseteq N$ is a submodule, and $\psi:N/K\to L$ is an injective $R$-module homomorphism.  Write $\varphi:N\to L$ for the composition of $\psi$ with the quotient homomorphism $N\to N/K$, so $\ker(\varphi)=K$.

That is, the map $\varphi$ is exactly a map satisfying the hypotheses of Theorem 8, and $K$ is its kernel (where what we know about $K$ is that the quotient $N/K$ is a quotient that embeds into an $S$-module).  So let $\Phi:S\otimes_R N\to L$ be the map provided by Theorem 8 using the map $\varphi$.  Then for each $n\in N$, $\varphi(n)=\Phi(\iota(n))$.  In particular, if $n\in \ker(\iota)$, then $\varphi(n)=\Phi(0)=0$, so $n\in\ker(\varphi)$.

Answer (score 0):

Put the maps into the diagram. Now take anything in $\ker \iota$, say $n$. By the diagram in Thm 8, it gets sent to $0$ in $S \otimes N$ which, since $\Phi$ is a homomorphism, then gets mapped to $0$ in $L$. Thus, by commutativity of the diagram, so then does $\varphi (n) = 0$ meaning that $n \in \ker \varphi$.